# assinging values in a string to an array or variables

Tags: c++, string, integer

I have a string:

```
std::string values= "1 2 3 4 5";
```

and I have variables:

```
int v1{};
int v2{};
int v3{};
int v4{};
int v5{};
```

how can I assign the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 that are inside the values string to variables v1,v2,v3,v4,v5?

Comment: Don't do this; instead split your input by space and store the text numbers in a collection such as a list.

Comment: my function takes a string as parameter and string's format is "1 2 3 4 5";  I have to assign the numbers inside the string to int variables v1, v2, v3, v4, v5. How can I add the content of this format string to the variables?

Comment: Remember in `values`, `'1'` is the ASCII digit for `'1'` with a value of `49` not `1`, see [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: I'm afraid I've still could not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need using the [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) member functions to operate on your `values` string isolating the beginning digit for each number and using [std::basic_string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to obtain the substring of digit(s) you pass to [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert from the string of digits to numeric value.

You make things harder by saving the individual converted values to individual variables instead of adding each converted value to a container such as `std::vector`. You can do this manually, it simply requires you to keep a counter of which variable is to be assigned to next and then logic to coordinate the counter value to the block of code making the assignment of the converted value to that variable. A `switch (counter) { ... }` makes about as much sense as anything else.

To work down the string you can use the member functions [std::basic_string::find_first_not_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) (to skip whitespace to the beginning digit of a number and then use [std::basic_string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to find the next whitespace after the digit(s) -- defining the begin and end position for the substring of numbers to convert.

There are many other ways to approach this, but putting what is outlined above altogether, you can do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {
    
    std::string values {"1 2 3 4 5"};
    int v1{}, v2{}, v3{}, v4{}, v5{};
    constexpr int nvars = 5;            /* number of variables */
    size_t n = 0, pos = 0;              /* var counter & pos in string */
    
    /* loop while n less than nvars find start of digit in string */
    while (n < nvars &&
          (pos = values.find_first_not_of (" \t\n", pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        /* find end position after sequential digits */
        size_t endpos = values.find_first_of (" \t\n", pos);
        /* use stoi (substr (pos, length)) to convert to number */
        int value = std::stoi (values.substr (pos, endpos - pos));
        switch (n) {    /* var counter coordinates assignment to var */
            case 0: v1 = value; n++; break;
            case 1: v2 = value; n++; break;
            case 2: v3 = value; n++; break;
            case 3: v4 = value; n++; break;
            case 4: v5 = value; n++; break;
            default: std::cerr << "count error: we shouldn't be here.\n";
                return 1;
        }
        pos = endpos;   /* update next start position to current end */
    }
    /* output results */
    std::cout << "v1: " << v1 << "\nv2: " << v2 << "\nv3: " << v3 <<
                "\nv4: " << v4 << "\nv5: " << v5 << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** you can employ a `try ... catch ...` block to catch any exceptions thrown by the conversion with `std::stoi` -- that is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

Running the program fills `v1` through `v5` with the numbers from your `values` string:

```
$ ./bin/stringtovars
v1: 1
v2: 2
v3: 3
v4: 4
v5: 5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code snippet to achieve the above query asked using Java:

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    String var = "1,2,3,4,5";
    List<String> newList = Arrays.asList(var.split(","));
    int v1 = Integer.parseInt(newList.get(0));
    int v2 = Integer.parseInt(newList.get(1));
    int v3 = Integer.parseInt(newList.get(2));
    int v4 = Integer.parseInt(newList.get(3));
    int v5 = Integer.parseInt(newList.get(4));
    System.out.println("v1: " + v1 + "\nv2: " + v2 + "\nv3: " + v3 + "\nv4: " + v4 + "\nv5: " + v5);
}
```

}

Comment: I am downvoting because while your answer might help for Java, the OP is using C++.  The syntax between the two is very different.

Comment: I'm so sorry not to tell that it's C++  And as a format I have to use spacesinstead of commas.

Comment: The question asked was in C++ and not in java